# Custom alert box using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom alert box. It was working previously and I haven't changed anything on my website so I am not sure why this would be throwing and error now.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var information_object = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
    $(".content").click(function() {
        var info = information_object[$(this).data('id')];
        if (info) {
            var warning;
            if(info.status == 3){
                warning = "High Voltage Detected";
            }else if(info.status == 4){
                warning = "Caution is Recommended"
            }else{
                warning = "Ok";
            }
            Alert.render("temp: " + info.temp + "&#0153" + "<br>" + "Address: " + info.address + "<br>" + "Date: " + info.date + "<br>" + "Status: " + warning);
        } else {
            alert("Invalid ID: " + id);
        }
    });
});
</script>

 <script
    function CustomAlert(){
        this.render = function(dialog){
            var winW = window.innerWidth;
            var winH = window.innerHeight;
            var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
            var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
            dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
            dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
            dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
            dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "temp Warning Information";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
            document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
        }

        this.ok = function(){
            document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    var Alert = new CustomAlert();
</script>
```

Small portion of CSS file containing dialogbox properties.

```
#dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#dialogbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:7px; 
    width:550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ 
    background:#FFF; 
    margin:8px; 
}
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ 
    background: #666; 
    font-size:25px; 
    padding:10px; 
    color:#CCC; 
    text-align: Center
}
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ 
    background:#333; 
    padding:20px; 
    color:#FFF; 
}
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ 
    background: #666; 
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:right; 
}
```

Reading the console of chrome it reports the error Uncaught "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" on the dialogoverlay.style.display = block.
Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Chances are that your JS loads before the element loads. It then isn't able to perform the ```.getElementById``` resulting in a not found element. You can't change the style of a not found element. Make sure to either wrap the code in a ```window.onload``` or place it at the bottom of your webpage.

Comment: in console run `document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');` do you get an element? Is something calling the render method before the element exists on the page? Add a breakpoint inside the render method and step through your code when it runs (you can do this in dev tools just search for debugging and the browser you are using).

Comment: I ran document.getElementById('dialogoverlay'); and it did receive a null value. I'm going to post the snippet of code that actually creates the alert box as well as some of the css.

Comment: Not really familiar with browser debugging tools but I will give that a look into! Thanks for the suggestion will probably be extremely helpful down the road.

Comment: Figured it out! My html document was messed with and a large portion of it was missing. Just rolled back to a previous version!
Thank you everyone for the help, sorry the solution was so boring, the debugging tool helped a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have a element on your page with the id `dialogoverlay`

If so, check if the javascript is on the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` closing tag

If none of those solutions works for you, can you please post a example of your html?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to make sure you don't have the relevant code deleted in your html file. Just in case anyone wants to use above code here is what you also need in your html.

```
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```